# How to generate PUT signed URL to entire folder in Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: java, google-cloud-storage

I would like to generate PUT signed URL that gives permission to upload many files to the specific folder. Then I would like to specify the actual filename in the folder during the file upload. How can I achieve that in Java using Google Cloud Storage client?

Ideally, the client that uploads files with generated URL could be written in any language.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GCS Signed Urls with subfolder in bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40423370/gcs-signed-urls-with-subfolder-in-bucket)

Comment: The above question is related to GET signed URL. Here I was asking about PUT.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, the Google Cloud Storage API does not support creating a signed URL based on a prefix.

A technical item to note is that folders do not exist in Google Cloud Storage. The namespace is flat. The concept of folders and separators (/) are just object name characters. All objects are located in the bucket root namespace.

Note: Cloud CDN does support `URLPrefix` for signed URLs. This will not help you with `PUT` requests but might be useful information for other readers [link](https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/using-signed-urls#url-prefix) interested in content caching.